# Binding "суждения" and "доля погрешности" together in Russian

Tags: выражения

Do "суждения" and "доля погрешности" go along well in Russian?

For example,

> That makes your суждения subject to a certain доля погрешности.

Or

> You must keep in mind that as much as we respect this scholar, his суждения
>   still have some доля погрешности.

I know that "доля погрешности" is a term mostly used in statistics in Russian, but can it also be applied in describing someone's general judgments (that is, not based on any statistical data)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In principle they can co-exist, the phrase is fully comprehensible. However as you yourself admit it's a technical scientific term and so it's not a particularly good fit for such categories as judgement and opinion.

Instead one can say

> That makes your суждения subject to a certain доля погрешности.
>
> ---
>
> Это привносит в твои суждения определённую долю **субъективности**/делает твои суждения несколько **субъективными**

and

> You must keep in mind that as much as we respect this scholar, his
>   суждения still have some доля погрешности.
>
> ---
>
> Стоит учитывать/иметь в виду, что суждения этого учёного не свободны от/не лишены определённой **субъективности**/некоторой (доли) **субъективности**

Answer (score 4):

Its can be used altogether with some connecting word(s). For example:

> Он говорил об этом достаточно уверенно, но мне все-таки показалось,
>   что в его суждениях могла быть опредленная доля погрешности.

But this is a very specific combination, so you should only use it if you know exactly when it's appropriate.
In example above, using "оценки" is better than "суждения":

> Он говорил об этом достаточно уверенно, но мне все-таки показалось,
>   что в его оценках могла быть опредленная доля погрешности.